# Null value in map to list jolt transform

Tags: json, transform, transformation, jolt

I'm modifying a map to an array and select only specific attributes from inner object. With my spec, i'm getting a 'null' value as first object in the result and all other data comes correctly.

Input

```
{
  "testSubmissionIdentifier": 37523,
  "testSubmissionComments": "Sample Request Comments",
  "testSubmissionDetails": {
    "1": {
      "testDetailsLineIdentifier": 1,
      "testProperty": 2,
      "testMethod": 3,
      "testCondition": 4,
      "testStandard": 5
    },
    "2": {
      "testDetailsLineIdentifier": 21,
      "testProperty": 22,
      "testMethod": 23,
      "testCondition": 24,
      "testStandard": 25
    }
  },
  "xyz": 157216
}
```

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "testSubmissionIdentifier": "testIdentifier",
      "testSubmissionDetails": {
        "*": {
          "testDetailsLineIdentifier": "testSubmissionDetails[&1].testDetailsLineIdentifier",
          "testStandard": "testSubmissionDetails[&1].testStandard"
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

Output
First element in `testSubmissionDetails` is a `null`, how do i get it removed?

```
{
  "testIdentifier" : 37523,
  "testSubmissionDetails" : [ null, {
    "testDetailsLineIdentifier" : 1,
    "testStandard" : 5
  }, {
    "testDetailsLineIdentifier" : 21,
    "testStandard" : 25
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "get rid of the null" in the first shift.   Your input data, as "1" and "2" as keys, that you are then using as indexes into your testSubmissionDetails array.

Shift is doing what it is told, and putting the data into the 1st and 2nd places in that array, and leaving a null in the Zeroth index.

To fix this, do another shift, that explicitly matched the Zeroth item and does nothing with it.

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "testSubmissionIdentifier": "testIdentifier",
      "testSubmissionDetails": {
        "*": {
          "testDetailsLineIdentifier": "testSubmissionDetails[&1].testDetailsLineIdentifier",
          "testStandard": "testSubmissionDetails[&1].testStandard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // pass thru testIdentifier
      "testIdentifier": "testIdentifier",
      //
      // "rebuild" the testSubmissionDetails array w/out the Zeroth null item
      "testSubmissionDetails": {
        // match the Zeroth item and do nothing with it
        "0": null,
        // accumulate the rest of the data into a 
        //  testSubmissionDetails array.
        "*": "testSubmissionDetails[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```